# is_alive() always returns False when called on a Thread from inside multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use a thread inside a process, I would also like to check if the thread is still running from within the process. The problem I'm facing is that when I run the same code inside a process `is_alive()` called on the thread always returns `False`.

```py
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        i = 0 
        while i < 10:
            print ("worker running..")
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1

class ProcessClass:
    def run_worker(self, worker):
        self.worker = worker
        self.worker.daemon = True
        self.worker.start()
        i = 0
        while i < 12:
            print (F"Is worker thread alive? {self.worker.is_alive()}")
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1

worker = WorkerThread()
processclass = ProcessClass()

# Calling directly works as expected
processclass.run_worker(worker)
```

When I call the method directly `is_alive()` works as expected, but when calling the method inside a process, it always returns `False`

```py
# Calling inside a process always returns False
parentProcess = Process(target = processclass.run_worker, args = (worker,))
parentProcess.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process`es are separate *processes*; threads are local to a single process. Even when you `fork` (the default mechanism behind `Process` on UNIX-like systems), only the thread that `fork`ed continues to exist in the new process, no other thread survives the `fork` (this is why mixing threads and `fork` is dangerous; if one of those other threads holds a lock at the time of the `fork`, that lock remains held by a non-existent thread in the child).

If you want the thread to run in the child, create it there (within the function passed as the `target` to `Process`), not in the parent process.

Comment: Could you give examples of "only the thread that forked" and "no other thread" in your answer?

Comment: @Crispy13: Not sure what you mean? If you have Thread A and Thread B running, and Thread B calls `fork`, then the newly forked process has a single thread running that picks up immediately after the `fork` in the same state Thread B was in before the `fork` (aside from the difference in `fork`'s return value). There is no equivalent to Thread A in the child process, because only the forking thread (B) continues to exist in the child process.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the thread class, not an instance, and have `run_worker` create the instance.

```
class ProcessClass:
    def run_worker(self, worker):
        self.worker = worker()
        ...

worker = WorkerThread
```

This way the thread is created in the child process rather than in the parent with a reference passed to the child.